# Efficient algorithm to turn matrix subdiagonal to columns r

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, transformation

I have a non-square matrix and need to do some calculations on it's subdiagonals. I figure out that the best way is too turn subdiagonals to columns/rows and use functions like cumprod. Right now I use a for loop and exdiag defined as below:

```
exdiag <- function(mat, off=0) {mat[row(mat) == col(mat)+off]}
```

However it to be not really efficient. Do you know any other algorithm to achieve that kind of results.

A little example to show what I am doing:

```
exdiag <- function(mat, off=0) {mat[row(mat) == col(mat)+off]}
mat <- matrix(1:72, nrow = 12, ncol = 6)
newmat <- matrix(nrow=11, ncol=6)
for (i in 1:11){
   newmat[i,] <- c(cumprod(exdiag(mat,i)),rep(0,max(6-12+i,0)))
}
```

Best regards,
Artur

Comment: Why not just make the matrix square and then extract the diagonal

Comment: I don't really understand. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Please can you include a reproducible example (including expected output) so we can see what you are after

Comment: Sure, I added an exmaple to show what I am doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest but by far the most cryptic solution to get all possible diagonals from a non-square matrix, would be to treat your matrix as a vector and simply construct an `id` vector for selection. In the end you can transform it back to a matrix if you want.

The following function does that:

```
exdiag <- function(mat){

  NR <- nrow(mat)
  NC <- ncol(mat)
  smalldim <- min(NC,NR)
  if(NC > NR){
    id <- seq_len(NR) + 
      seq.int(0,NR-1)*NR +
      rep(seq.int(1,NC - 1), each = NR)*NR


  } else if(NC < NR){
    id <- seq_len(NC) + 
      seq.int(0,NC-1)*NR +
      rep(seq.int(1,NR - 1), each = NC)

  } else {
    return(diag(mat))
  }
  out <- matrix(mat[id],nrow = smalldim)
  id <- (ncol(out) + 1 - row(out)) - col(out) < 0
  out[id] <- NA
  return(out)
}
```

Keep in mind you have to take into account how your matrix is formed.

In both cases I follow the same logic:

- first construct a sequence indicating positions along the smallest dimension
- To this sequence, add 0, 1, 2, ... times the row length.

This creates the first diagonal. After doing this, you simply add a sequence that shifts the entire previous sequence by 1 (either down or to the right) until you reach the end of the matrix. To shift right, I need to multiply this sequence by the number of rows.

In the end you can use these indices to select the correct positions from mat, and return all that as a matrix. Due to the vectorized nature of this code, you have to check that the last subdiagonals are correct. These contain less elements than the first, so you have to replace the values not part of that subdiagonal by NA. Also here you can simply use an indexing trick.

You can use it as follows:

```
> diag1 <- exdiag(amatrix)
> diag2 <- exdiag(t(amatrix))
> identical(diag1, diag2)
[1] TRUE
```

In order to come to your result

```
amatrix <- matrix(1:72, ncol = 6)
diag1 <- exdiag(amatrix)
res <- apply(diag1,2,cumprod)
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
t(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for that idea, I'll try to fit it to my problem. According to wikipedia subdiagonals are elements Aij which follow the rule j=i+k and k > 0. Due to that I ignore upper-triangle part of matrix (including diagonal) and I am also interested in ones that do not have element in every column (so the ones close to the end of the matrix).

Comment: @Swistak I've added the code you need in order to reproduce your result according to that definition of subdiagonals. To get the exact same, you have to transpose the end result. Otherwise you can fill the matrix rowwise in the `exdiag` function, but then you have to check the NA additions.

Comment: Thanks, that code is 10x faster than one I was using before!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the diag() function.

```
exdiag <- function(mat, off=0) {mat[row(mat) == col(mat)+off]}

exdiag2 <- function(matrix, off){diag(matrix[-1:-off,])}
```

Speed Test:

```
mat = diag(10, 10000,10000)

off = 4

> system.time(exdiag(mat,4))

  user  system elapsed 
  7.083   2.973  10.054 

> system.time(exdiag2(mat,4))

   user  system elapsed 
  5.370   0.155   5.524 

> system.time(diag(mat))

   user  system elapsed 
  0.002   0.000   0.002
```

It looks like that the subsetting from matrix take a lot of time, but it still performs better than your implementation. May be there are a lot of other subsetting approaches, which outperforms my solution. :)

Comment: Diag in R allow only to take a diagonal, and I want to extract subdiagonals. I was looking for function similar to diag from matlab but it seems that there is no function like that and I don't really know how to efficiently write it myself.

Comment: modify the diag() function with subsetting: step 1. take a the subset of matrix, 2. use use diag()

Comment: Unfortunately, when you add column subsetting then diag has worse performance than my previous function. I tried it as:


    `exdiag2 <- function(mat, off=0) {
      n = ncol(mat)
      ifelse(off==0,diag(mat),diag(mat[-(1:off),-((n-off+1):n)]))
    }`

Comment: Hi @Swistak, I updated my solution, please check it.

Comment: Hi @xirururu,

unfortunately it is not helpful on my machine  :( 

`> time <- proc.time()
> t1 <- exdiag(tryryry, 4)
> time2 <- proc.time()
> t2 <- exdiag2(tryryry,4)
> time3 <- proc.time()
> time2 - time
   user  system elapsed 
   2.64    0.97    3.93 
> time3 - time2

   user  system elapsed 
   3.70    0.25    4.09 `

Comment: @Swistak I updated my code, can you run the same code on your computer, and tell me the speed?

Comment: I check that and it still slower (user time 3.86 vs 2.65). It seems that I cannot get it faster than I do now